# How to reload pool_hba.conf in pgpool without restart?

Tags: postgresql, pgpool

How can we reload pool_hba.conf after a config change, is there a way without restarting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According the documentation, it is possible to reload pgpool conf files [`without restarting it`](https://www.pgpool.net/docs/pgpool-II-3.4.0/doc/pgpool-en.html#reload)

```
pgpool [-c][-f config_file][-a hba_file][-F pcp_config_file] reload
```

> -a, --hba-file=HBA_CONFIG_FILE
> Set the path to the pool_hba.conf configuration file
> (default: /etc/pgpool2/pool_hba.conf)
>
> -F, --pcp-file=PCP_CONFIG_FILE
> Set the path to the pcp.conf configuration file
> (default: /etc/pgpool2/pcp.conf)
>
> -f, --config-file=CONFIG_FILE
> Set the path to the pgpool.conf configuration file
> (default: /etc/pgpool2/pgpool.conf)

So we can build the following command

```
pgpool -a /etc/pgpool2/pool_hba.conf reload
```

Also, to reload PostgreSQL configuration files you can run [`pg_reload_conf()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-admin.html):

```
SELECT pg_reload_conf();

 pg_reload_conf 
----------------
 t
```

From the documentation: `pg_reload_conf () → boolean`

> Causes all processes of the PostgreSQL server to reload their
> configuration files. (This is initiated by sending a SIGHUP signal to
> the postmaster process, which in turn sends SIGHUP to each of its
> children.)

Comment: can you help me create the exact command, the location of my pool_hab.conf is /etc/pgpool-II/pool_hba.conf

Comment: @Rahul perhaps something like : `pgpool  -a  /etc/pgpool-II/pool_hba.conf -F /etc/pgpool-II/pcp.conf reload` or even  `pgpool -a /etc/pgpool-II/pool_hba.conf  reload`

Comment: do i really need to reload all three or just one will do ?? Coz i have changed pool_hba.conf

Comment: @Rahul what about `pgpool -a /etc/pgpool-II/pool_hba.conf  reload`?